# GridView in OnRowDeleting no rows are found

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a couple of GridViews on the page and they both have the problem. When the OnRowDeleting function is fired the GridView (and sender) find no rows.  I created the GridView in the following way:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gridview9" runat="server" 
        DataKeyNames="id" 
        OnRowDeleting="deleteNumberFrom9" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CssClass="mGrid"
        AlternatingRowStyle="alt">
        <Columns>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="product_key" headertext="PRODUCT KEY"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:boundfield datafield="first_name" headertext="FIRST NAME"/>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="last_name" headertext="LAST NAME"/>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="email" headertext="EMAIL"/>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="phone_number" headertext="PHONE NUMBER"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="DELETE NUMBER" ShowDeleteButton="True"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DeleteText="Delete" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The grid is populated from a MySQL database:

```
    GridView gv = gridview9;
    String connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ToString();
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    if (addPhone)       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_number", "%" + phoneNumber + "%");
    if (addEmail)       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "%" + email + "%");
    if (addFirstName)   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", "%" + firstName + "%");
    if (addLastName)    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", "%" + lastName + "%");
    if (addProductKey)  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_key", "%" + productKey + "%");
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    gv.DataSource = ds;
    gv.DataBind();
    gv.Visible = true;
```

Finally, the onRowDeleting function is:

```
    protected void deleteNumberFrom9(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int SID = Convert.ToInt32(gridview9.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        String phone_number = e.Values[4].ToString();
        deleteNumber(SID, phone_number, 9);
    }
```

When I run the page, gridview9 properly returns 2 rows but when I click delete in one of the rows and the deleteNumberFrom9 is fired gridview9.Rows.Count is 0 instead of 2. When I add sender to watch list and view the row count it is also 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must rebind the data to the GridView after deleting the record in the database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}

protected void gv_Deleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    deleteNumber(SID, phone_number, 9);
    BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    ...
    gv.DataSource = ds;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```